# Finding the radius of convergence of $\sum_{0}^{\infty}z^{n!}$ ?

Tags: real-analysis

I was thinking about the problem that says: What is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{0}^{\infty}z^{n!}$ ?

Please help. Thanks everyone in advance for your time.

Comment: 22 minutes. $ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean the radius of convergence of $$\sum_{0}^{\infty}z^{n!}$$

We have $a_{n!}=1$ for all $n!$. Then by Hadamard's theorem we have $$\lim_{n=m!,n\rightarrow \infty}\sup (1)^{1/n}=1$$

Comment: Hadamard is overkill, no? Isn't it more-or-less trivial that it diverges at $z=1$, and converges (by comparison to $\sum z^n$) for $|z|\lt1$?

Comment: Hadamard is overkill. But the question indicates he/she clearly does not know Hadamard.

Comment: Which seems to be a reason (apart from the obvious conceptual one) **not** to use Hadamard, no?

Comment: This is a good point. Thank you.